# How to deserialize XML string fragment?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an object that has some properties that are XML string fragments. I want to take those and further deserialize them into objects for easier use. How can I do that using the .NET XML Serializer?

Here's an example of the XML string fragment:

```
<Addr1></Addr1>
<Addr2></Addr2>
<Addr3></Addr3>
<Addr4></Addr4>
<City></City>
<State></State>
<PostalCode></PostalCode>
<Country></Country>
```

So far my attempts have resulted in this exception:

```
<Addr1 xmlns=''> was not expected.
```

Comment: so you fragment has no root element?

Comment: Why not simply add a root element and then deserialize?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to deserialize the fragments into objects I assume you have a strongly typed object so you could just create a helper method to add a root element using the type name of the object you are trying to deserialize

Example:

```
public T DeserializeFragment<T>(string xmlFragment)
{
    // Add a root element using the type name e.g. <MyData>...</MyData>
    var xmlData = string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", typeof(T).Name, xmlFragment);
    var mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var reader = new StringReader(xmlData))
    {
        return (T)mySerializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Addr1 { get; set; }
    public string Addr2 { get; set; }
    public string Addr3 { get; set; }
    public string Addr4 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}



string fragment = @"<Addr1>2</Addr1>
                    <Addr2>2</Addr2>
                    <Addr3>2</Addr3>
                    <Addr4>2</Addr4>
                    <City>2</City>
                    <State>2</State>
                    <PostalCode>2</PostalCode>
                    <Country>2</Country>"; 

var result = DeserializeFragment<MyData>(fragment);
```